# Q:Power BI - showing monthly values up to selected month and YTD value

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm new to Power BI and would be greatfull if someone could help me with following:

My data model looks like this:

[image: Data model]

I want to achieve a matrix which shows monthly values starting the year up to selected period from a slicer and MYTD value for the last period.

Selecting 1.3.2021 gives:

[image: 1_3_2021]

Selecting 1.2.2021 gives:

[image: 1_2_2021]

Please note:

1. Period date format is d/m/yyyy
2. It is not possible to calculate the MYTD values they are loaded directly from the database

Thanks for help

Marek